# Pyspark JDBC write json data into Redshift withour backslash and double quotes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am migrating the postgres data to redshift but I am facing one issue while writing the records into the Redshift because of json data type. Actually it is writing into the redshift but it is adding backslashes and double quotes. It is escaping the double quote characters.

I am doing this in Pyspark code which I will be running in AWS EMR.

Here is the code I am using.

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameNaFunctions
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, arrays_zip, concat_ws, expr, to_json, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

# Create Spark and Glue contexts
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
sparkSession = glueContext.spark_session

job = Job(glueContext)
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

logger = glueContext.get_logger()

# Read data from Aurora Postgres using SQL queries

src_tables = [
    "users.property_configuration2"
]

for table in src_tables:
    
    
    postgres_df_1 = sparkSession.read.format("jdbc").\
                      options(
                              url=jdbcUrl, 
                              dbtable="users.property_configuration",
                              user=src_username,
                              password=src_password,
                              driver='org.postgresql.Driver').\
                      load()
                      
    
    df_schema = postgres_df_1.schema
    
    # Iterate over the fields in the schema
    for field in df_schema.fields:
        logger.info(f"Field taken -------------  : {field.name}, {field.dataType}")
        if isinstance(field.dataType, ArrayType):
            logger.info("Column '{}' is of ArrayType".format(field.name))
            postgres_df_1 = postgres_df_1.withColumn(field.name, to_json(postgres_df_1[field.name]))
 
    postgres_df_1 = DataFrameNaFunctions(postgres_df_1).fill("")
    
    
    # Write new records to the target table
    postgres_df_1.write.format("jdbc").options(
        url=dst_jdbc_url,
        dbtable=table,
        user=dst_username,
        password=dst_password
    ).mode('append').save()
    
    logger.info(f"Redshift Insertion completed for table : {table}")
    
# Commit the job
job.commit()
```

Example data in the source postgres for one of the column is:

```
{"logo":"xyz", "name":"abc"}
```

But after writing it into redshift I am getting the data in that column like this:

```
"{\"logo\":\"xyz\", \"name\":\"abc\"}"
```

I do not want data like this I want the normal format.

Also since spark consider the json data as string so may be it is doing like that.

Please let me know if you can help me out in resolving this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can remove `to_json` function as the source is already in JSON string format. And might also need to parse this json data as a string  to redshift.

Comment: If I will remove to_json then for array data it will throw an error while loading that data into redshift that "cannot infer array<string>". And I have more than 150 million records then can you please tell me how to parse this data as I can not do it row by row